# converting between time zones in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a date in UTC (`timestamp with time zone`):

```
test=# select ('2018-05-31T21:00:00+00'::timestamptz);
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2018-05-31 21:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

I want to convert it to another timezone, for example UTC+2. The documentation states that `at time zone` should do it for me:

> **Experession**
>   `<timestamp with time zone> AT TIME ZONE <zone>`
>   **Return type**
>   `timestamp without time zone`
>   **Description**
>   Convert the given time stamp with time zone to the new time zone, with no time zone designation

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT).

But when I try to do it, I get strange results:

```
test# select ('2018-05-31T21:00:00+00'::timestamptz) at time zone 'utc+2';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2018-05-31 19:00:00
(1 row)
```

I am pretty sure that 21 hours in UTC is 23 hours in UTC+2 (that's the reason for `+2`, after all).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the POSIX standard that [according to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) decrees that

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations west of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.